# MinGW-w64 string array crashing

Tags: c++, arrays, string, crash, mingw-w64

If I try to compile and run this

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string strs[5];

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error message of

> The procedure entry point ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library (path to exe).

I am using mingw-w64 gcc version 6.2.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1) and have already tried (i686-posix-sjlj-rev1).

Is there another compiler version that does not encounter this bug or something I can do to my code to make it compile?

Comment: Try compiling with `-static-libstdc++`.

Comment: @KerrekSB that worked but I would like to know why

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but with mingw-w64 gcc from MSYS2 `g++ test.c` is enough,